# Orbeon Forms: Passing External Data into a Repeating Grid

Tags: orbeon

We are struggling on how to pass a table of external data into a repeating grid.

Our external (SAP) system needs to supply data into the form in the following format:

[image]

The table rows above does add a second row, but doesn't put the FIELD_VALUE in the correct row - it currently puts the Row1A/B in the second row, whereas it should put it in the first row. I've tried loads of variations, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Demo form:
https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/9effd72b808f92e5a2511d2121abfe42d6469c5b

Thanks in advance

PeteA

Comment: In general, the way to do this would be to use the [action syntax](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/advanced/services-and-actions/actions-syntax). Is that what you are doing? How can I reproduce the problem you see with the demo form you pointed to? I ask because it does not seem to point to a service.

Comment: Hi Alex,
The only data we can pass into the form is via the table format given above.
I suspect we wont be able to answer this question here  - I'll probably need to get SAP involved.
PeteA

Comment: Hi Pete, yes, this sounds like the type of question that would be easier to resolve if we could have a meeting and use screen sharing. But please let me know if there is anything else you feel I can help with even with the limited bandwidth we have here.